# Clearcase undo Delivery from a deleted view

Tags: view, clearcase, rebase

I stopped my deliver because some files were corrupted.
So I deleted my view and created a new one.

But when I want to "undo deliver", I have this message :

```
Can't find root directory of snapshot view with tag "MyView1".
Unable to determine view root of snapshot view "MyView1".
View "MyView1" is inaccessible.
```

I tried to follow this [instructions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124390#rename-view) but it don't work.

How can I cancel that deliver operation?

Comment: Normally if you try to deliver again it will bring you to a window where you can undo the delivery.

Comment: Yes the message appear when I check "Undo deliver" or "Complete" in this window

Answer (score 1):

Try the same deliver using command-line [`cleartool deliver`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm)

You need to reset the view used for that deliver to a new one.

```
-reset -to integration-view-tag
```

> You must not remove the developer view when a deliver operation is in progress.
>   However, if the integration view is lost during a deliver operation, you can use the `-reset -to` option to reset a new integration view so you would be able to cancel the operation. You can also use this option with `-resume` and `-complete`.

Use that to resume the delivery. Once the delivery is in progress, interrupt it (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and then try to cancel it.

Comment: i have this message when i use cleartool deliver : Unable to determine default deliver target for integration stream ...
and -reset is an unknow command

Comment: @AlexisB What ClearCase version are you using?

Comment: Rational ClearCase Explorer 8.0.0.7

Comment: @AlexisB I suppose you are not using the double-quotes? It should be `cleartool deliver -reset -to xxxxx` (plus other parameters)

Comment: I tried with old and new tag name and i have the help command appear for each with no error and i have my problem again

Comment: @AlexisB the goal is to reset the deliver to a new view, so I confirm you should use the new view tag. Can you show the exact command line used (obfuscating the name of the view and pvob)?

Comment: @AlexisB Can you have a look at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm, and add to that command the name stream (source stream: the one from which you are delivering): `-stream astream@\apvob`

Comment: An expert of my company help me and resolve the problem :D
But i don't know how.
Thanks guys
#vonC I tried your last post but i have the help command again

Comment: @AlexisB could you ask your expert what was the solution?